# Await for react-router history.goBack to complete

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm in a route that indexes an array in state. When clicking a button, I want to delete that item out of state. Before doing this, I want to go back to another route that doesn't use the item. I do this to avoid a TypeError when indexing the item that no longer exists.

Is it possible to wait for the route change to complete before updating state? It seems like there is no promise capability with useHistory.

Minimal example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      stuff: [{
        message: 'hello'
      }]
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    console.log('mounted')
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/1'>
          <Child
            stuff={this.state.stuff} callback={() => {
              this.props.history.goBack()
              this.setState({
                stuff: []
              })
            }}
          />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/'>
          <button onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/1')}>
            Go to friend
          </button>
          home
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    )
  }
}

const Child = ({ callback, stuff }) =>
  <>
    <button onClick={callback}>
      Go back
    </button>
    {stuff[0].message} friend
  </>

const withUseHistory = (Component) => {
  return function WrappedComponent (props) {
    const history = useHistory()
    return <Component {...props} history={history} />
  }
}

const AppWithHistory = withUseHistory(App)

const wrapper = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <AppWithHistory />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  wrapper)
```

Comment: If your routing to a component, then can you not use useEffect or componentDidMount to execute the state update as needed? Mounting likely means the routing has occurred successfully right?

Comment: The component housing the state is the root component of the application. I'm not sure if it re-mounts upon route change, I'll test it out.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I've updated the example to be more complete. The component does not re-mount when using history, so using componentDidMount doesn't work. I've found a solution through using history.push instead of history.goBack. It seems history.push is synchronous while goBack is async.

Comment: If you are on the same component and need it to “refresh” then you need to use keys in the routed component to have it actually re-mount.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution through using history.push instead of history.goBack:

```
this.props.history.push('/')
this.setState({
  stuff: []
})
```

It seems history.push is synchronous while goBack is async.

Answer (score 0):

```
history.goBack();

// Register a popstate listener that executes only once during the next history entry change
window.addEventListener('popstate', onPopStateCallback, {once: true});
```

We can register a callback for the next history entry(pop state) update